# Why is copy-ctor called instead of implicit conversion operator when using variadic arguments

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, conversion-operator

I have following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Dog
{
public:
    Dog() : ptr(nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    Dog(const Dog&) = delete;
    Dog(Dog&&) = delete;

    inline operator void*() const
    {
        std::cout << "conversion op" << std::endl;
        return ptr;
    }

private:
    void* ptr;
};

void dosomething_buf(void*)
{

}

void dosomething(const Dog& d)
{
    dosomething_buf(d);
}

int main()
{
    Dog d;
    dosomething(d);
}
```

This code works as intended and calls ctor and implicit conversion operator once.

However if I change the signature of `dosomething_buf(void*)` to `void dosomething_buf(...);`

I get following compile-error:

```
[build] [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/playground.dir/test.cpp.o
[build] /media/rbs42/data/Gebos/RBS42/PlayGround/test.cpp: In function ‘void dosomething(const Dog&)’:
[build] /media/rbs42/data/Gebos/RBS42/PlayGround/test.cpp:31:20: error: use of deleted function ‘Dog::Dog(const Dog&)’
[build]      dosomething_buf(d);
[build]                     ^
[build] /media/rbs42/data/Gebos/RBS42/PlayGround/test.cpp:11:5: note: declared here
[build]      Dog(const Dog&) = delete;
[build]      ^~~
```

Why does the compiler call the copy-ctor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you expect the `void*` conversion operator to be invoked at all, since there's no `void*` argument anymore?

[C-style variadic functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic) (which, by they way, are **not** recommended in C++ since we have varadic templates) take an arbitrary number of arguments by value. When calling `dosomething_buf(d)`, you're copying `d` to initialize one of the variadic arguments.

Comment: I see, thank you! This code ist just a minimal working example. Actually I am passing something to JNI, which unfortunately uses C-syste variadic functions also in the C++ interface.

Comment: So you changed the code to the point where you got it working, and the original problem is no longer visible..

Comment: No. I just produced a MWE to issue the problem! I am now using an explicit conversion function like void* to_buf() const; for the classes I use in the actual code and use these methods instead of the implicit conversion operator.